# php printing numbers in a shape using less than 2 for loops

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
<table>
<tr
<td align="center">
<?PHP

$b = 1;
for ($a=1; $a<=1; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;
    echo "<br>";
}

$b = 2;
for ($a=1; $a<=2; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

}

echo "<br>";
$b = 4;
for ($a=1; $a<=3; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

 }
echo "<br>";
$b = 7;
for ($a=1; $a<=5; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

{
echo "<br>";
$b = 12;
for ($a=1; $a<=5; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

}
echo "<br>";
$b = 17;
for ($a=1; $a<=4; $a++)
 {
     echo $b++;

}
echo "<br>";
$b = 21;
for ($a=1; $a<=3; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

}
echo "<br>";
$b = 24;
for ($a=1; $a<=2; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

}
echo "<br>";
$b = 26;
for ($a=1; $a<=1; $a++)
{
    echo $b++;

 }

 ?>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

I am trying to use for loops to make a shape that looks something along the lines of this:

I have managed to do it, but using way too many loops (9), I want to be a little less than this. Anyone have any help?

P.S its meant to be a diamond shape with the numbers 1-26

```
   ![sort of like this][1]
```

Comment: Along the lines of what? An empty space?

Comment: I recall doing exactly this in python for homework but can't for the life of me remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$arr = array(1,2,4,7,12,17,21,24,26,27);
for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    for($j=$arr[$i-1]; $j<$arr[$i]; $j++) {
      echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, just to give an idea:

```
$i = 0;
$leaps = array(1,2,4,7,12,17,21,24,26);
foreach($leaps as $leap){
    for($j = 1; $j<=$i; $j++){
       echo $leap++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I Did'nt quite mention the numbers have to show up in a diamond shape.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$rowsUntilMiddle = 5;
$startnumber = 1;

$totalrows = $rowsUntilMiddle*2-1;
$i = $startnumber;
$numInRow = 0;
// each row
for ($row=1; $row<=$totalrows; $row++) {
    if ($row <= $rowsUntilMiddle) {
        $numInRow++;
    } else {
        $numInRow--;
    }
    // each number
    for($j=0; $j<$numInRow; $j++) {
        echo $i;
        $i++;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```